# How to replace downloaded image with same file name in storage from server?

Tags: java, android

I implement the function in which user can save image from the server.
Here is my code.

```
BasicImageDownloader imageDownloader = new BasicImageDownloader(new BasicImageDownloader.OnImageLoaderListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(BasicImageDownloader.ImageError error)
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error code " + error.getErrorCode() + ": " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgressChange(int percent)
                                    {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(Bitmap result)
                                    {
                                        final Bitmap.CompressFormat mFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
                                        final File myImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                                                + "Android" + File.separator
                                                +"data" +File.separator
                                                +"test" +File.separator
                                                + "profileimage" +File.separator
                                                + mPost.get(i).getUid() + "." + mFormat.name().toLowerCase());
                                        BasicImageDownloader.writeToDisk(myImageFile, result, new BasicImageDownloader.OnBitmapSaveListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onBitmapSaved() {
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image saved as: " + myImageFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onBitmapSaveError(BasicImageDownloader.ImageError error) {
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error code " + error.getErrorCode() + ": " +
                                                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                error.printStackTrace();
                                            }


                                        }, mFormat, false);
                                    }
                                });
                                imageDownloader.download("link", true);
```

It works great but whenever the same name exists in the storage location . It throw the exception:"file is already exists".
Now the problem is how to replace downloaded image whenever same file exists in the storage location?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of BasicImageDownloader.writeToDisk() ?

Comment: ok please wait until i corrected my question.

Comment: Is it reasonable to put whole class file in stackoverflow, it is very long and this was i pickup from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the BasicImageDownloader class on the web.
The last parameter of writeToDisk is for overwriting.
So if you set it to true like this:

```
BasicImageDownloader.writeToDisk(..., true);
```

it should overwrite the file.